# Getting User Anonymous error while accessing api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I am trying to access an api endpoint and I am getting the following error.The api has been built using node and mongo and hosted in aws. We never used AWS Elastic search service.

```
{
"Message": "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet on resource: material-definition"
}
```

When I hit the browser second time without hard refresh then I get the json data. I can't understand the deep cause.

Any suggestion/hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: please provide more information. What's the url like? whats the second hit url like? check for cookie, localstorage addition as well.

Comment: https://api.xxx.co.uk/events/eventid/?token=tokenid. The second hit url is exactly same as first. When I copy the api code in another server it runs well.

Comment: @ShrihariBalasubramani Nothing in local storage and no cookies stored.

Comment: check for the access logs. Caching or something could be happening

Comment: @ShrihariBalasubramani Cleaned the cache but still getting that error sometimes and sometimes not.